# I'm getting about 40Mbps transfer rater over WiFi (from phone to Linux). Is it that slow because of the SDCard on the phone?

Tags: wi-fi, file-transfer

I have a WiFi connection which, in the settings, says:

> Transmit link speed
> 866Mbps
>
> Receive link speed
> 780Mbps

I've installed PowerFTP on my phone and transferred a large video file (about 40 min.) from my Android (Pixel 5a) phone to my Linux computer. My network is a 1Gbps all around (switch, NICs, WiFi router) except for the WiFi transmission itself (obviously).

The transfer rate shown by PowerFTP is around 5Mb/s (or ~40Mbps).

Why is that transfer rate so low? Is there something else limiting the speed along the way?

---

Update:

My Network looks more or less like this:

```
+-------+        +-------------+        +--------+        +------+
|       |        |             |        |        |        |      |
| Phone |<::::::>| WiFi Router |<------>| Switch |<------>|  PC  |
|       |  WiFi  |             |  LAN   |        |  LAN   |      |
+-------+        +-------------+        +--------+        +------+
~700mbps         ~700Mbps  1Gbps          1Gbps            1Gbps
```

The LAN has a switch and that connection is local (as in 192.168.x.x).

There are other devices on the WiFi (3 phones, a laptop--which was off when I tested the above).

Of course, I can see some WiFi devices from my neighbors... so I understand there can be interference there.

Comment: The higher Wifi connection speed values you have included are these values measured e.g by an app or web site or is this just the connection speed shows in WiFi settings? If it is the latter the shown value is a theoretical value that can never be reached. Also keep in mind that the air is a shared media used by multiple WiFi and other systems like Bluetooth baby phones, ...

Comment: @Robert That's the values found in the WiFi settings of that specific connection. I understand that there could be collisions (and thus some slowdown), but what I'm getting is about 20× less!

Comment: Is your Linux PC connected via WiFi or Ethernet? If it is WiFi then the data have to be transmitted twice through the air phone > router > PC. Also check how many other WiFi s around use the three channels of your WiFi. If you use a WiFi with more bandwidth try to narrow it to reduce collisions with other Wifis - sometimes a slower WiFi connection speed can result in a higher practical speed.

Comment: Additionally you shoud perform a real network test like iperf3, there should be also apps available that can do so. Run the iperf3 server on your PC and test from the phone.

Comment: Okay, I have iperf3 installed in Termux, I'll check with that and report. Otherwise I added some info about my network. The WiFi is on the LAN as far as my PC is concerned.

Comment: can you try another app please? https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=net.xnano.android.ftpserver, 

https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=dk.tacit.android.foldersync.lite, 

https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=lysesoft.andftp

Comment: I can remember of similar issue with [LAN drive](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=fr.webrox.landrive) app. at least they mention in app description

Answer (score 1, accepted):

that's limitation from PowerFTP. before buying ask [support](https://powerftp.medialux.app) if pro version will increase speed (not sure about this)

Comment: Do you have proof of that? I can't find anything other than your answer which would confirm your statement. It's not that I don't believe you, but I would think that they would mention it somewhere if that was the case?

Comment: just my common sense of how things work - that's why you should ask support for confirmation

Comment: Please do some test. downvote to indicate PowerFTP is not the cause. **Only** upvote/accept to confirm PowerFTP **has** some speed limitation (in whatever kind). That's my sense of how community can create references if no other sources exist

Comment: Okay, I had the opportunity to test with [AndFTP](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=lysesoft.andftp) which you proposed above and it worked as expected! Much faster. So I guess PowerFTP is rate limiting you (at least the free version) even though their info doesn't say anything about that...